# Miniconda で仮想環境のライブラリを import できない

Tags: python, windows, miniconda, conda

Windows の Miniconda で仮想環境を作ったのですが，activate して Python を実行してみたところ，Miniconda 本体の方の site-package を見てしまっているのか仮想環境の方の site-package のライブラリを `import` できません．  
環境変数の `PYTHONHOME` を削除すると `import` できるようにはなるのですが，そのような環境変数の変更なしに実現する方法はあるのでしょうか．

```
C:\>conda create -n myenv numpy
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
    numpy:  1.9.1-py27_0
    python: 2.7.9-1

C:\>activate myenv
Activating environment "myenv"...

[myenv] C:\>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Miniconda\envs\myenv:
# 
numpy 1.9.1   py27_0
python 2.7.9    1 

[myenv] C:\>python

>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>>
```

環境変数の `PYTHONHOME` には C:\Miniconda を，`PYTHONPATH` には C:\Miniconda\Lib\site-package を設定し，上で作成した [myenv] を activate した状態での `sys.path` の結果が以下のものになります．

```
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Miniconda\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Miniconda\\envs\\myenv\\python27.zip', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\DLLs', 'C:\\Miniconda\\lib', 'C:\\Miniconda\\lib\\plat-win', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Miniconda\\envs\\myenv', 'C:\\Miniconda']
```

また，そこから `PYTHONHOME` を削除して同じように `sys.path` を実行した結果が以下のものになります．

```
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Miniconda\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Miniconda\\envs\\myenv\\python27.zip', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\envs\\myenv\\DLLs', 'C:\\Miniconda\\envs\\myenv\\lib', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Miniconda\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\lib-tk', 
'C:\\Miniconda\\envs\\myenv', 'C:\\Miniconda\\envs\\myenv\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: activateしたあたりから先のコマンドラインの入出力を貼ってください

Comment: 仮想環境を作成してそこにnumpyをインストールする手順からすべて記載してもらうのが良さそうです。追記をお願いします。

Comment: `sys.path`の中身を見せてもらえませんか。